# What is a Fine-Print Country™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

<sub>*In the spirit of the What is a [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion)/[Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463), a special brand of [Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aphrase+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) and [Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22I+call+it%22+title%3A%22what+is%22+title%3Aword+is%3Aquestion+user%3A463) puzzles.*</sub>

---

If a **Country** conforms to a special rule, I call it a **Fine-Print Country™**.
Use the examples below to find the rule.

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{Fine-Print }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\ \def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Countries }^™\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Non-}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{24px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2017.02.04}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{  Luxembourg                    }&\text{     Montserrat                                         }\\ \hline
\text{  Brazil                        }&\text{     Madagascar                                         }\\ \hline
\text{  Philippines                   }&\text{     Malawi                                             }\\ \hline
\text{  Syrian Arab Republic          }&\text{     China                                              }\\ \hline
\text{  Italy                         }&\text{     Sudan                                              }\\ \hline
\text{  Kiribati                      }&\text{     Tunisia                                            }\\ \hline
\text{  Georgia                       }&\text{     Gambia                                             }\\ \hline
\text{  Gibraltar                     }&\text{     Algeria                                            }\\ \hline
\text{  France                        }&\text{     Burkina Faso                                       }\\ \hline
\text{  Uzbekistan                    }&\text{     Isle of Man                                        }\\ \hline
\text{  Kenya                         }&\text{     US Virgin Islands                                  }\\ \hline
\text{  Norway                        }&\text{     Croatia                                            }\\ \hline
\text{  Panama                        }&\text{     Wallis and Futuna                                  }\\ \hline
\text{  Albania                       }&\text{     Mayotte                                            }\\ \hline
\text{  India                         }&\text{     Bonaire                                            }\\ \hline
\text{  Colombia                      }&\text{     Saint Barthelemy                                   }\\ \hline\end{array}$$

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
Fine-Print Countries™,Non-Fine-Print Countries™  
Luxembourg,Montserrat  
Brazil,Madagascar  
Philippines,Malawi  
Syrian Arab Republic,China  
Italy,Sudan  
Kiribati,Tunisia  
Georgia,Gambia  
Gibraltar,Algeria  
France,Burkina Faso  
Uzbekistan,Isle of Man  
Kenya,US Virgin Islands  
Norway,Croatia  
Panama,Wallis and Futuna  
Albania Mayotte  
India,Bonaire  
Colombia,Saint Barthelemy
```

**What is the special rule that these countries conform to?**

---

<sub>The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is a Fine-Print Country™ without relying on the other words. These are not the only examples of Fine-Print Countries™. You may use comments to ask for information as to whether a specific country qualifies as a Fine-Print Country™. No purchase necessary. To obtain a Fine-Print Country™ game piece, send a self-addressed, stamped email to ChowzenRules@PuzzlingSE.com. Game void where prohibited. Submission of answers to this question automatically installs the Awesome Chowzen Toolbar and changes your browser's default Start Page and Search Engine to Chowzen.com. This puzzle uses cookies to enhance your puzzling experience. Reading this paragraph indicates your acceptance of cookies to be stored in your web browser. These Cookies may or may not contain nut protein, gluten, MSG, soy and fish eggs. This puzzle may constitute a choking hazard for young children. No animals were harmed during the creation of this puzzle. The answer to this puzzle may not be used for the development, design, manufacture or production of nuclear missiles, or chemical or biological weapons. This puzzle may have been manufactured either wholly or in part from concentrate and contains no fruit juice. Consuming raw or undercooked puzzles, riddles, or shellfish may increase your risk of foodborne illness. Management is not responsible if this puzzle turns out to be a gateway to Narnia. If solving this puzzle results in more than four consecutive hours of excitement, consult a physician. The creator of this puzzle asks that you please enjoy puzzling responsibly.</sub>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Fine-Print Countries are those where the

> **F**irst **P**air of letters of the country name gives the top-level internet domain name.

For the countries these are

> Luxembourg - lu, Montserrat - ms
>   Brazil - br, Madagascar - mg
>  Philippines - ph, Malawi - mw
>  Syrian Arab Republic - sy, China - cn
>  Italy - it, Sudan - sd
>  Kiribati - ki, Tunisia - tn
>  Georgia - ge, Gambia - gm
>  Gibraltar - gi, Algeria - dz
>  France - fr, Burkina Faso - bf
>  Uzbekistan - uz, Isle of Man - im
>  Kenya - ke, US Virgin Islands - vi
>  Norway - no, Croatia - hr
>  Panama - pa, Wallis and Futuna - wf
>  Albania - al, Mayotte - yt
>  India - in, Bonaire - bq
>  Colombia - co, Saint Barthelemy - bl
>
>   List of [TLDs](https://icannwiki.org/Country_code_top-level_domain)

Comment: I was going for [this](https://www.worldatlas.com/aatlas/ctycodes.htm), but yours works just as well (and is likely derived from my list, right?) I'll "tick" this answer in just a tick.

Comment: Italy Iceland Thailand Spain Armenia Spain Ethiopia !

Comment: Yes, it appears so. :)